# D2 unit-testing fixtures

Tags: unit-testing, fixtures, d

I just wanted to drop by and ask if someone knows if there is any method/workaround to get fixtures with the in-built D2 unit testing capabilities.

I could not find anything on the official D2 site (the unit testing documentation does not mention fixtures) so I guess it's not possible but still hope that this assumption is wrong :)

If it is not possible I would be happy if someone could point me to a unit-testing framework for D2 which supports fixtures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dunit](https://github.com/jmcabo/dunit)

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising.